# How to install a Brother MFC-5890CN scanner/printer

Tags: 12.04, printing, scanner

I had my Brother MFC-5890CN scanner/printer working with Ubuntu 10.*.

Now that I have upgraded to 12.04 LTS, the printer is still working but my scanner fails.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu **12.04** is no longer supported but here is an answer for **16.04**: [How to get a Brother DCP-350C scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012496/how-to-get-a-brother-dcp-350c-scanner-working/1013560#1013560).

To summarize the answer, first go to the [Brother Printer/Scanner website](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj410w_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625). Then select your printer model:

[image: Brother Scanner New]

Select the right product (Printer/Scanner). In the printer icon for `MFC-J410W`, click the link **Not your product?** and a selection page appears:

[image: Brother Scanner Model Select]

The screen below is for the MFC350 printer/scanner which has a sub-menu for "DCP 3 Series" which leads to a specific model:

[image: Brother Scanner Model DCP-350C]

My printer is the fourth icon in the panel, which being 3 icons wide is immediately below yours. I'll select that and it has a sub-menu for "DCP 7 Series" which after clicking presents:

[image: Brother Scanner Model DCP-7065DN]

I'll click on **DCP-7065DN**. You would have already selected **DCP-350C** on the previous screenshot.

After selecting the printer model, you are asked for your OS. It defaults to Linux and ".rpm". The default is ".rpm" which stands for **Red Hat** or **Arch Linux** or something like that. Change the distro to ".deb" which stands for **Debian** which is really **Ubuntu**.

[image: Brother Scanner Select OS.png]

---

Above is a summary of the link. Click on the link for the full tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I found information that might help your problem from this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xsane/+bug/578620).

You could either run `xsane` with `root` or you may `adduser <user> lp`. I tried and they both work.

Comment: this is not ideal and should be avoided if there is another fix.

Comment: It is possible to use xsane without root if one installs the brother-udev-rule-type package on brothers website.