# How to get a Brother DCP-350C scanner working?

Tags: drivers, scanner, brother, sane, simplescan

Downloaded and installed the linux drivers from the Brother site [here](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html).

But the scanner still wasn't recognised.

You can see here, the drivers installed successfully:

```
$ dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
ii  brother-cups-wrapper-common                          1.0.0-10-0ubuntu6                                        amd64        Common files for Brother cups wrapper packages
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                              1.0.0-1                                                  all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                          0.2.4-1                                                  amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan2                                              0.2.5-1                                                  amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                               3-5~ubuntu1                                              amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                                1.4-1                                                    amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

And here, you can see the installed driver thinks it is not 'registered':

```
$ brscan-skey -l

 DCP-350C          : brother2:bus3;dev1  : USB                  Not registered
```

When I open Simple Scan, it tells me I have a Brother scanner but that I need to install the drivers.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f9:01d0 Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-350C

$ sudo dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brother-cups-wrapper-common                          1.0.0-10-0ubuntu6                                        amd64        Common files for Brother cups wrapper packages
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                              1.0.0-1                                                  all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                          0.2.4-1                                                  amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan2                                              0.2.5-1                                                  amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                               3-5~ubuntu1                                              amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                                1.4-1                                                    amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Brother seems to have removed the linux o/s config instructions from its support pages - i.e. [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html#u9.10) and [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101), which had been the source of earlier solutions to this problem given [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967467) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594558). The OS support information [page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqcategory.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&ftype2=190) in its FAQS and Troubleshooting section refer only to Windows and Macintosh. If you look elsewhere, you will find a [page](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn2.html?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&redirect=on) of linux information. It says "The Brother Linux scanner driver works only with a superuser by default". It points to a [page](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&redirect=on) where it says is given the means to make the scanner work for non-sudo users - perhaps, then, SimpleScan. That page contains fix downloads for numerous OSs, but nothing later than Ubuntu 13.10. Downloading and installing that file all the same does nothing to make the scanner work. If you grub around long enough you will [find](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&redirect=on) there is a linux troubleshooting FAQ after all - just not in the place where you would expect to find it. Getting this Brother scanner to work is like threading a needle in a wind tunnel. The first item on the linux FAQ is 'I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. I cannot scan from my Brother Machine'. That is close enough. It [says](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&redirect=on#f00107) 'Install libusb-0.1-4'. (The Brother driver had dependencies but it did not bother to check them). I do have this usb lib installed already anyway.

One of the earlier solutions (for a different Brother scanner - and the Brother support page with the solution has since disappeared), is quite helpful. It [says](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967467) to put a line in '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules', though in fact it should, on my 16.04 at least, be /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules. And the line it asks you to add includes a reference to a product ID for a different Brother scanner. Looking on the sane [website](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE) for a DCP-350C product ID (it wouldn't be DCP-350C -- that would be too easy -- the earlier solution is for a DCP-7030 and that has a product ID of "01ea")... so where were we?... looking on the sane website for a DCP-350C product ID. The sane [page](http://www.sane-project.org/cgi-bin/driver.pl?manu=Brother&model=&bus=usb&v=&p=) for Brother scanners has no entry for the DCP-350C. It says if your device isn't there it's not supported. It says the page was last updated on Oct 05 2003. That's fourteen and a half years ago. I believe the 350C came out a few years later, in 2007.

So the old solution for the DCP-7030 said to add edit the sane config thus:

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

And to add this (in the right place):

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01ea", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Since my config appears to be in 60-libsane.rules and I don't have a product code, I edited the config thus:

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
```

And added:

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

And restarted the machine. This did not work.

I also moved some files the Brother intsall routine seems to put in the wrong place - at least, according to reports elsewhere such as [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967467).

That involved copying Brother files from cp /usr/lib64/ to /usr/lib. (I had downloaded and installed the 64-bit version of the Brother driver).

The instructions to do this seemed out of date. And since Brother's website says its Brscan2 driver must be used with the DCP-350C, the filenames may differ. I copied mine thus:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so /usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1 /usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0 /lib/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so /usr/lib/sane
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1 /usr/lib/sane
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1.0.7 /usr/lib/sane
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so /usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1 /usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib
```

This blind alley was suggested by Brother itself. It's linux [FAQ](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&redirect=on#f00101) for the DCP-350C (if you can find it), says (for "Ubuntu 11.10 or higher"):

```
Copy the following files under /usr/lib64/ to /usr/lib/.
```

Another tip was to actually run the brscan-skey file that is offered as download with the driver, by simply entering brscan-skey at the command line.

At some point, something must have gone right because the Brother driver now tells me the device is recognised:

```
$ brscan-skey -l

 DCP-350C          : brother2:bus3;dev1  : USB                  Not registered
```

However, SimpleScan still says no devices are recognised.

Also, Brother says that brscan-skey allows scanning to be performed from the scanner's own console, using its 'scan-to-file' and 'scan-to-image' options. When I do so, the scanner says 'Connecting to PC', but nothing more happens.

I can get the 350C to scan when I call it from a trial version of a commercial linux scanning tool called VueScan. But the trial version puts water marks across the scanned image, making it useless to me. Moreover, the full version is expensive, and demands an annual subscription. And I only came across it while trying to find a way to get SimpleScan to work - or indeed, any open source scanning software.

The point is that VueScan just works. (But it does so in a way that leaves the scanner dysfunctional to other tools). It proves the scanner can be used with open source tools on Ubuntu. The question is how.

Comment: After installing the Linux drivers from the Brother site for my Brother DCP-7065DN, and then adding the `# Brother scanners` snippet to `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules`, Simple Scan still would not recognize the device.  After I spent a few hours banging my head against the wall, I discovered that in Simple Scan's Preferences, the Scan Source drop-down menu had two similarly-named entries; after switching to the second one, I was up and scanning!  Not sure if something similar has happened to you, but I thought I would just put this here...

Answer (score 9):

## Short Answer

The drivers you found are old versions:

```
$ dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
ii  brother-cups-wrapper-common                1.0.0-10-0ubuntu6                                        amd64        Common files for Brother cups wrapper packages
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                    1.0.0-1                                                  all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                0.2.4-1                                                  amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan2                                    0.2.5-1                                                  amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     3-5~ubuntu1                                              amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4-1                                                    amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

The newest versions are:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i brother
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                    1.0.2                                        all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                0.2.4-1                                      amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.4-3                                      amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7065dn:i386                  2.0.4-2                                      i386         Brother DCP7065DN CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp7065dnlpr:i386                          2.1.0-1                                      i386         Brother DCP-7065DN LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     3-5~ubuntu1                                  amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4-1                                        amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

- `udev` rule upgraded from `1.0.0-1` to `1.0.2`
- `brscan2` version `0.2.5-1` upgraded to `brscan4` version `0.4.4-3`

Also you have a generic `cups-wrapper` where as mine is model specific.

---

## TL:DR; Very, very LONG ANSWER

Much of the long answer is trial and error. You need only follow **Step 1**, **Step 2**, the first part of **Step 3** (stop at selecting *scanner only*). Then skip down to **Step 6** and **Step 7**.

---

## Background

I have a Brother DCP-7065DN which is a nice monochrome double sided laser printer. I've had it for three years but have never used the scanner feature primarily because "whose got paper to scan in an electronic world?". Due to your question I thought it was time to get the scanner function working.

## Comparing DCP-7065DN to DCP-350C

According to this post in [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246878) the same Brother Driver tool works for both your **DCP-350C** and my **DCP-7065DN** printer.

---

## Current installation tools

Your question contains no less than 15 links and I noticed the site of your first [link](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html) is out-dated:

[image: Brother Scanner Old]

The **Ubuntu Forums** Q&A I linked above contains a more current installation tool [link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj410w_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625):

[image: Brother Scanner New]

#### Notice the Release Date is Christmas 2017, only a few months old.

Rather than repeating your steps I'll start a fresh install (of the scanner only) using the **Ubuntu Forums** link above.

---

## Installation Step 1 - Select Printer

Start by selecting the right product. In the printer icon for `MFC-J410W`, click the link **Not your product?** and a selection page appears:

[image: Brother Scanner Model Select]

Your printer can be found in the first icon which has a sub-menu for "DCP 3 Series" which leads to your specific model:

[image: Brother Scanner Model DCP-350C]

My printer is the fourth icon in the panel, which being 3 icons wide is immediately below yours. I'll select that and it has a sub-menu for "DCP 7 Series" which after clicking presents:

[image: Brother Scanner Model DCP-7065DN]

I'll click on **DCP-7065DN**. You would have already selected **DCP-350C** on the previous screen shot.

---

## Installation Step 2 - Select Operating System (OS)

After selecting the printer model you are asked for your OS. It defaults to Linux and ".rpm". The default is ".rpm" which stands for **Red Hat** or **Arch Linux** or something like that. Change the distro to ".deb" which stands **Debian** which is really **Ubuntu**.

[image: Brother Scanner Select OS.png]

Click the `Search` button.

---

## Installation Step 3 - Download Software

Now that the preliminaries are finished and the Command Line aficionados and GUI haters in Ubuntu-Verse have put my name on their dart boards we get to select the software to download:

[image: Brother Scanner Software Select.png]

The model icon in the top-left corner should be **DCP-350C** for you but it is **DCP-7065DN** for me.

The first section is for printer drivers but we don't need that as both our printers print fine. The last section is for source code but we don't need that. If we did we probably wouldn't be on this website. The middle section contains the **scanner drivers**:

[image: Brother Scanner Select Arch.png]

Here we need to select the architecture: **32-bit** or **64-bit**.

I've read a 32-bit driver won't work on my 64-bit arch so I'm only going to download #3 & #4 for now. I may come back and grab #1 if I need the driver?

### Installation Step 3-A)

#### Download `Scan-key-tool 64bit (deb package)`

After selecting #3 scanner option we see your model number on line #2 and my model number on the last line (of the screen shot)...:

[image: Brother Scanner scan-tool-key-64bit.png]

...So assuming all works well for me it should all work well for you!

You need to agree to the EULA (End User License Agreement) and then download the `.deb` file.

The file downloaded is:

- brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb, size 50.9 KB, date 03/12/2014

The follow-up instructions on the web page says:

#### brscanX should be installed first

### Installation Step 3-B)

#### Download `Scanner driver 32bit (deb package)`

So we have to go back a screen and download #1 (**
Scanner driver 32bit (deb package)**). The file downloaded is:

- brscan4-0.4.4-4.i386.deb, size 63.9 KB, date 09/22/2017

#### Notice the date is only a 6 months old!

### Installation Step 3-C)

#### Download `Scanner Setting file (deb package)`

At the same time #1 is downloaded, we'll download #4 (**Scanner Setting file (deb package)**). The file downloaded is:

- brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2-0.all.deb, size 1.6 KB, date 11/25/2016

#### Notice this the version number is different than yours!

---

## Installation Step 4 - `sudo dpkg -i ...`

To summarize the packages downloaded:

- 1. brscan4-4.4-4.i386.deb
- 3. brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
- 4. brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2.0.all.deb

We will first install #1, then #4, `reboot` and finally install #3:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.4-4.i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brscan4:i386.
(Reading database ... 1147453 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brscan4-0.4.4-4.i386.deb ...
Unpacking brscan4:i386 (0.4.4-4) ...
Setting up brscan4:i386 (0.4.4-4) ...
This software is based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2-0.all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brother-udev-rule-type1.
(Reading database ... 1147495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2-0.all.deb ...
Unpacking brother-udev-rule-type1 (1.0.2) ...
Setting up brother-udev-rule-type1 (1.0.2) ...
ls: cannot access '/etc/udev/rules.d/*.rules': No such file or directory
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$
```

#### Ohh No! Error on the last line.

No idea why `ls` was generating an error because the directory is there and three rules exist. We can see one of them has just been set up:

```
$ ll /etc/udev/rules.d/*brother*.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1004 Mar 10 16:59 /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1.rules
```

Oh well... let's proceed anyway. Looking at the new Brother `udev` rule all it does after a whole bunch of code is set:

```
ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Now it's time to post this answer as is and `reboot`.

After rebooting let's install the last file:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brscan-skey.
(Reading database ... 1147499 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb ...
Unpacking brscan-skey (0.2.4-1) ...
Setting up brscan-skey (0.2.4-1) ...
```

*Interesting* that there is more than a million files on my system. Those 25 kernels add up over time.

---

## Installation Step 5 - Testing

I cheated a bit and found this: [Brother DCP-7065DN, Ubuntu 14.04 64bit: Can print to network printer but cannot use the scan function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486699/brother-dcp-7065dn-ubuntu-14-04-64bit-can-print-to-network-printer-but-cannot) which recommended these steps:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ brscan-skey
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ brscan-skey -l

 DCP-7065DN        : brother4:bus4;dev7  : USB                  Active

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$
```

So far, so good. The answer (no long sure if it's sure valid) says you need to put `brscan-skey` into your **Startup Applications** and you need `gimp` installed. Comment below if you need help doing this.

Apparently `xsane` is needed for scanning:

```
$ sudo apt install xsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
   (...BLAH, BLAH, BLAH...)
Setting up xsane-common (0.999-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xsane (0.999-3ubuntu1) ...
```

### `xsane` = extremely insane

After installing type `xsane` in the terminal and get:

[image: xsane as user.png]

After closing the error message, `xsane` tries to scan for devices and eventually replies there are none. Oh Joy, Oh Bliss. The Brother website says scanning is designed to be done as root so we'll type `sudo xsane` and now we see:

[image: xsane as sudo.png]

Sounds scary but regular user couldn't find a scanner so let's see if `sudo` does. Select `Continue at your own risk` button. After window greys out for a few momments the same response as regular user appears: `No devices available`.

### Software method doesn't work, try hardware method

Using the scan key on the Brother MFC generates this message:

[image: scan button on brother.png]

Well at least there is communication between scanner and computer because `gimp` started up automatically.

I never rebooted after installing `brscan-skey` so do it now out of hope / desperation.

---

## Step 6 - Go back and download CUPS Wrapper

Rebooting didn't work so I'll go back and install the CUPS Wrapper tool dated `12/25/2017` which has not been installed on my system. You have an older version of on your system:

[image: Brother CUPS wrapper download.png]

There are five download packages. When downloading the first one (CUPSwrapper) this dialog box appears:

[image: Brother CUPS wrapper download open_save.png]

- Change option from `Open` to `Save`!
- Click `OK`

Open terminal, change to `~/Downloads` and verify file exists:

```
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ ll *.gz*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick    24666 Mar 11 08:24 linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz
```

After downloading these instructions appear on the website. Abbreviated format follows:

```
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ sudo su
root@alien:/home/rick/Downloads# 

root@alien:/home/rick/Downloads# bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1 DCP-7065DN # Change DCP-7065DN to DCP-350C
You are going to install following packages.
   dcp7065dnlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.deb
   cupswrapperDCP7065DN-2.0.4-2.i386.deb
   brscan4-0.4.4-3.amd64.deb
   brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
OK? [y/N] ->
```

Uh-Oh... It's selecting `brscan4-0.4.4-3.amd64.deb` but earlier I had installed `brscan4-0.4.4-4.i386.deb` which was a newer version but the wrong architecture. This could explain the errors I had!

Select `y` to proceed. Big license agreement pops up. Select `y` to proceed. Another license agreement pops up. Select `y` to proceed. The script runs `apt install` on it's own.

A prompt appears:

```
Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->
```

For yours and mine **USB Printer** we select `n`.

Next it prompts for a test print. To kill another tree select `y`. Yeah the test print works and I now have a printed page I can scan later!

A third big license agreement now appears so, select `y` to proceed.

It's all finished so `reboot`.

---

## Step 7 - Test simple-scan

After `reboot` check the installation in terminal and perform simple scan:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ brscan-skey
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ brscan-skey -l

 DCP-7065DN        : brother4:bus4;dev7  : USB                  Active

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i brother
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                    1.0.2                                        all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                0.2.4-1                                      amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.4-3                                      amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7065dn:i386                  2.0.4-2                                      i386         Brother DCP7065DN CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp7065dnlpr:i386                          2.1.0-1                                      i386         Brother DCP-7065DN LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     3-5~ubuntu1                                  amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4-1                                        amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ simple-scan
```

After all the hard work we are rewarded with a scan:

[image: Brother simple scan sans sudo]

Comment: Nice answer. The 'outdated' pages I got from Brother's DCP-350C page. Looking at it today, they seem to have changed. They now point to something more recent, like the screenshots you have given. There is also a page of pre-install directions, which may or may not have been there before. I had not seen it. It says to do such things as update firmware and create symbolic links. I had seen nothing of this either in forums or on Brother's website. The pre-install info is here: http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&redirect=on

Comment: The linux pre-install instructions are problematic, however. They say update the firmware first. But they provide no link to do so. There is a firmware update link on the DCP-350C product page. But this has updates only for Windows and Mac. You can see that here: http://support.brother.com/g/b/midlink_os.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&site=pc&type2=4&orgc=gb&orglang=en&orgprod=dcp350c_all&targetpage=18

Comment: Hopefully, @WinEunuuchs2Unix, in the days you say it will take you to complete your answer, Brother will have finished updating its own!

Comment: @markling The answer is finally fInished! Note that even pressing the `scan` button on the scanner works to scan the image and invoke `gimp` image editor automatically. This could be the difference between your `brscan2` and my `brscan4` if it doesn't work for you. Installing the brother scanner could go down on record as the longest non-programming answer I've written :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Nice recipe.  Do you really need the `sudo` to `simple-scan`?  I assumed this was also a difference between `brscan2` and `brscan4`.

Comment: @oscar1919 No `sudo` is not required for `simple-scan` although I had read `sudo` so many times in Brother documentation it became a habit. I've revised the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I had used Brother's driver version 2 because when I went to the Brother support website and chose my scanner model, it said that I must install v2. It recommended v4 for other models. I'll give this a go. But I must admit I am daunted by the prospect of reading through your full answer, @WinEunuuchs2Unix. I'm not sure there's room for it on my bedside table. I mean, I've not even read War and Peace yet!

Comment: The steps you show for navigating Brother's web pages for a DCP-7065DN do not appear when you attempt to get drivers for a DCP-350C. It is completely different. I must therefore edit your post to remove the DCP-7065DN screenshots etc, despite all your hard work. Because it is not only irrelevant but also misleading. I shall try your instructions all the same.

Comment: Also, trial and error steps are deeply unhelpful, especially in something so fraught as fixing a driver for an out-of-date scanner.

Comment: I find your opening suggestion (install brscan4, etc.) worth a try, even though Brother says to use brscan2. But since your steps are contrary, I cannot follow them.

Comment: @markling I'm not sure what you mean that steps are "contrary". There are wrong steps to avoid: Steps 3 A)-C), Step 4 and Step 5. But I left these steps there to highlight problems others may have along with a instructions **NOT** to use them.

Comment: Your catalogue of mis-steps confuse the answer. The procedure is already fiendish. Your instructions don't work for the DCP-350C because the Brother pages for that printer install a different driver to the one you show here as a solution for the 7065DN. Not only that but you have overlooked the preconditions for installing the  accursed Brother driver - and those are also problematic. eg. installing 32-bit c libs which do not install.

Comment: The driver install tool you recommend requests pre-install steps that include the install of a 32-bit c library that has dependencies that cannot be met: gcc-4.8-base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1

Comment: @markling The pre-install steps can be safely ignored. The software works perfectly well on 64-bit platform as long as you click on the 64 bit version. Was this the reason you didn't accept the answer nor award the bounty?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you got 50 points off me cos half the bounty went to you by default. I am afraid I found your answer indigestible. But I wouldn't begrudge you the points you got for the effort you made to solve the problem.

Comment: Different versions of brscan (2, 3, 4) despite release date, seem to support DIFFERNT model sets, so they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with brother printer/scanner MFC-J625DW.
Apparently, some older versions of the driver (upto brscan4) put some files into the wrong folder.  This issue seems to be fixed now (moment of writing May, 2020).
(I have also been editing the 'rules' file , but in the end reverted everything as it did not solve anything.)

When it happens the fix is :
Check if the following directory exist.

For 64bit Users:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

For 32bit Users:
`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane`

Type the following command if the above directory exists.

For 64bit Users:
Command : `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

For 32bit Users:
Command : `sudo cp /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane`

To clarify I will list all actions I did to get my MFC-J625DW to work (reboot between some steps may be useful):

- download, unzip and run script for your device from
  support.brother.com (this installed all necessary packages for my
  device) Follow all instructions on that site.
- add myusername to the
  group lp, owning the scan device `sudo adduser <myusername> lp`
- if you need to find out the name of this group, switch on the device, do
  `lsusb`, note the busnr and devicenr of the brother, and execute `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/busnr/devicenr` (3 digits per nr)
- did the filecopying fix described above
- to enable all features of brscan-skey, I need gimp, sane and xsane
  `sudo apt install gimp`
  `sudo apt install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane`

Comment: Due to link rot - please copy the relevant parts of the link to your answer ! Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to use `ln` instead of `cp` here. No need to copy files when a hard link does the job too.

Comment: Bravo! It's that easy. And it even has the answer on the Brother DCP-350C FAQ, if you squint hard enough, or have special abilities such as thought and reading-comprehension. It only nearly solves the problem though. SimpleScan now recognises the scanner. But on attempting to scan, it says 'Unable to connect to the scanner' .

Comment: It seemed necessary also to "sudo cp -v /usr/lib64/libbr* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/", to correct and follow the other instructions on the Brother website. But this neither gets the scanner to actually scan.

Comment: Hm.  I also had to add my username to the group lp, because that is the group that owns the scan device. `sudo adduser <you> lp`.  Maybe check that.

Comment: To find this out, switch on your scanner and do `lsusb`.  Note the busnr and devicenr of the brother.  Then do `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/busnr/devicenr` (3 digits!) where you can see the group.

Comment: Added user to groups lp and scanner (doh), and still no sign of sentience in the Brother scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this problem finally by using the [Brother driver installer](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp350c_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625).

That might bust your software updates. So you may have to run a command to fix it afterwards:

`$ sudo apt-get -f install`

The problem seemed to be that the Brother website was directing linux users from its 350C page to old versions of its drivers and installers. That inevitably led me to descend into a frightening netherworld haunted by old forum posts that recounted other people's past horrors attempting to get their Brother scanners working. The posts here helped haul me out. But really the answer was simply to get the right Brother installer in the first place and ignore all the other advice. Although, having said that, I tried such a wide variety of fixes, many of which seemed to have some sort of partial success, that it is hard to say for sure what got it working in the end.

Comment: Congrats! Brscan-skey is only needed if you want to start a scan using the scanner menu/buttons e.g. scan-to-image, which opens gimp.  In my setup, I can do without sudo, maybe device dependent?  Anyway, I am out of recommendations.

Comment: I kind of thought you would find a solution before my multi-day answer was finished. Note that your `brscan2` driver might be out-dated and `brscan4` might be better but as of yet I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

After a huge struggle, the scanner of my good old DCP-350C works.
I am using Linux Mint 19.4, but it might give some clues to Ubuntu users as well. I have done all the written above and more, but still got no good result.

At last, I installed in this order:

```
dcp350clpr-1.0.1-1.i386
dcp350ccupswrapper-1.0.1-1.i386
brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64
brscan2-0.2.5-1.amd64
brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2-0.all
```

and in the end: "brother-cups-wrapper-extra" from the software manager.
The printer works fine, the scanner did not.

Next, I installed form the software manager `xsane`. As mentioned elsewhere, VueScan recognizes the scanner, but I figured there had to be a way of getting it to work without VueScan.

In `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules` I added:

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01ea", ENV{libsane_matched}="y
```

And in `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` I have changed

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664"
```

into

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0666"
```

Still no result, `simple-scan` can't find a device.

In the end I have copied all the files from "usr/lib64" to "usr/lib" including the file `Sane`.

And that did the trick!
The scanner works in `simple-scan` and `xsane`!

Disclaimer: I am not an Linux expert, but I was determined to make the scanner work. So most likely there are few steps that were unnecessary or improper. It was done by trial and error. Hope this is helpful to other Linux users.