# Brother Scanner MFC-7330CDW not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, scanner, ubuntu-drivers, brother

I recent acquired a brother MFC-7330CDW printer with a scanner. When I try to 'scan to pc', it says no pc found (on the scanner).

I've tried the following:

- Installed all drivers

  ```
  ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                    1.0.2                                      all          Brother udev rule type 1
  ii  brscan-skey                                0.2.4-1                                    amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
  ii  brscan4                                    0.4.9-1                                    amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
  ii  mfcl3770cdwpdrv:i386                       1.0.2-0                                    i386         Brother Laser Printer Driver
  ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     6-1build1                                  amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
  ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4.2-3                                    amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
  ```
- Configured the scanner (although I am getting this 'not responded message')

  ```
  Charlie           : brother4:net1;dev0  : 192.168.1.10         Not responded
  ```
- As per some suggestions on forums, added the line into the 60-libsane.rules file (though not sure I did this correctly, new to ubuntu and Linux more broadly)
- Installed and reinstalled drivers numerous times

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions? I'd really like to get the scanner to scan to my PC wirelessly.

Comment: Maybe check my answer and the other ones on this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012496/how-to-get-a-brother-dcp-350c-scanner-working/1013381#1013381  That answer was valid for 18.04.

Comment: Hey I gave this a go too, but it output a message along the lines of 'xxx file is the same as yyy file' over three lines (sorry not with my machine atm), and it still won't connect.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
I downloaded the latest brscan DEB file, installed it with Gdebi and then ran this command in the Terminal:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=(name your device) model=(model name) ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

In my case it looked like this:

```
sudo brsaneconfig4 -a name=MFC-J890DW model=MFC-J890DW ip=192.168.188.74
```

Then I checked if the scanner was added with:

```
brsaneconfig4 -q
```

and it printed:

```
* MFC-J890DW   [ 192.168.188.74]  MFC-J890DW
```

Then I opened Document Scanner and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I installed the driver months ago but I only configured the printer, not the scanner. So glad to find that the `brsaneconfig4` tool was already installed, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked like a charm on Neon running 20.04. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with my DCPL2550dw, but had to do a bit more work to get the scan button working:

1. Editing /opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/brscan-skey.config to set the variable "eth" to my actual network card device (obtained from the "ip addr" command).
2. Enabling SNMP on the printer through the printer's web administration interface.
3. Opening ports 54925/udp 56848/udp and 54921/tcp on my firewall using firewall-cmd.
4. Using "brscan-skey -u NAME" to set the PC name to the hostname of my system.
5. Running brscan-skey as a normal user and pushing the Scan button on the printer.

The scanned document is placed in a folder named "brscan" in your home directory.  This does not seem to be easily configurable without editing /opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/scripts/scantofile.sh directly and changing the OUTPUT variable on line 16.

Hope that helps someone!